# Short story about England right after nuclear war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

Read a story back in the 1980s in a sci-fi anthology about England just after a nuclear war. The government was trying to rebuild and everyone was suffering from radiation poisoning. Towards the end a mob of survivors captured several people in the government and wanted to know who started the war. I remember other nuclear war stories in the book as well just can't remember any details.

I seem to recall the cover being reddish-pink. Most if not all of the stories dealt with Cold War/Nuclear War themes. No aliens or spaceships. I could be misremembering but the title of the anthology was something like "The Best Science Fiction Stories of 1982". I've obviously Googled for that a few times, even changing the date and none of what I found seemed to be the one I was looking for. I could have missed something though. I do not remember any of the authors' names either (been too long ago).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions for asking story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any other details to [edit] into your question.  For example, do you remember anything about the cover of the book, even just the colour?

Answer (score -2):

I strongly suggest googling "nuclear war anthology". That turned up this one with a cover that one might stretch to be the one you're looking for:

[https://www.amazon.com/Countdown-Midnight-H-Bruce-Franklin/dp/0879979836](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0879979836)

This was, of course, a very common theme at that time, but I'm sure Amazon will turn it up.

Comment: Which story in *Countdown to Midnight* do you think matches the OP's description?